# Problem with changing src of the video element - React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Changing Video src won't have effect except using the key property on video element to trigger the change or changing ref.current.src by using useRef hook. But it produces flicker effect on mounting and unmounting.

I don't understand why it won't change the source or won't trigger the updated component with new value and second, how can i fix this flickering effect?

following is my component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import data from "./mockData";
import { Media } from "../types/index";
import PlayList from "./playList";
import UrlInput from "./urlInput";
import VideoFrame from "./videoFrame";
import VidoeControls from "./mediaControls";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

const MediaPlayer: React.FC = () => {
const [playlist, setPlaylist] = useState<Media[]>(data);
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [newUrl, setNewUrl] = useState<string>("");
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams({ i: "0" });

const currentMediaIndex = searchParams.get("i") ?? "0";

let videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

const handleUrlChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setNewUrl(event.target.value);
};

const handleAddMedia = () => {
    if (newUrl.trim() !== "") {
        const id = playlist.length + 1;
        setPlaylist((currList) => [...currList, { id, url: newUrl }]);
        setNewUrl("");
    }
};

const handleRemoveMedia = (id: number) => {
    setPlaylist((currList) => currList.filter((obj) => obj.id !== id));
};

const handleNext = () => {
    const currIndex = +currentMediaIndex;
    let newIndex = +currIndex + 1;
    newIndex = newIndex > playlist.length - 1 ? 0 : newIndex;
    setSearchParams(
        (prev) => {
            prev.set("i", newIndex.toString());
            return prev;
        },
        { replace: true }
    );
};

const handlePrevious = () => {
    const currIndex = +currentMediaIndex;
    let newIndex = currIndex - 1;
    newIndex = newIndex < 0 ? playlist.length - 1 : newIndex;
    setSearchParams((prev) => {
        prev.set("i", newIndex.toString());
        return prev;
    });
};

const handleFastForward = () => {
    if (videoRef.current) {
        videoRef.current.currentTime += 10;
    }
};

const handleRewind = () => {
    if (videoRef.current) {
        videoRef.current.currentTime -= 10;
    }
};

const handlePlayPause = () => {
    if (videoRef.current) {
        if (isPlaying) {
            videoRef.current.pause();
        } else {
            videoRef.current.play();
        }
        setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {}, [searchParams]);

return (
    <>
        {playlist.length > 0 ? (
            <>
                <div className="">
                    <div className="">
                        <PlayList
                            list={playlist}
                            onRemove={handleRemoveMedia}
                            activeIndex={+currentMediaIndex}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <UrlInput
                        onAddUrl={handleAddMedia}
                        onChange={handleUrlChange}
                        value={newUrl}
                    />

                    <VideoFrame
                        ref={videoRef}
                        onClick={handlePlayPause}
                        isPlaying={isPlaying}
                        source={playlist[+currentMediaIndex].url}
                    />

                    <VidoeControls
                        onBackward={handleRewind}
                        onForward={handleFastForward}
                        onPlayPause={handlePlayPause}
                        onPrevious={handlePrevious}
                        isPlaying={isPlaying}
                        onNext={handleNext}
                    />
                </div>
            </>
        ) : (
            <>no playslist</>
        )}
    </>
);
};

export default MediaPlayer;
```

and following is my video frame component

```
import { forwardRef, useEffect } from "react";

interface VidoComponentProps {
  ref: HTMLVideoElement;
  isPlaying: boolean;
  onClick: () => void;
  source: string;
}

const VideoFrame = forwardRef(function VideoPlayer({
    isPlaying,
    onClick,
    source
  }: VidoComponentProps,
  ref
) {
  useEffect(() => {
    //ref.current?.load();
    ref.current.src = source;
  }, [source]);

  return (
        <video ref={ref} autoPlay={isPlaying} onClick={onClick}>
            <source src={source} type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
  );
});

export default VideoFrame;
```

Answer (score 0):

"*In this code, a new key is generated using Date.now() whenever the source prop changes. This key is then used on the video element. This approach ensures that a new video element is created when the source changes, preventing the flickering effect and the load() method is called after updating the src to ensure that the video is reloaded with the new source*."

```
import { forwardRef, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";

interface VideoComponentProps {
  isPlaying: boolean;
  onClick: () => void;
  source: string;
}

const VideoFrame = forwardRef(function VideoPlayer(
  { isPlaying, onClick, source }: VideoComponentProps,
  ref
) {
  const key = useMemo(() => Date.now(), [source]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.src = source;
      ref.current.load();
    }
  }, [source, key]);

  return (
    <video key={key} ref={ref} autoPlay={isPlaying} onClick={onClick}>
      <source src={source} type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  );
});

export default VideoFrame;
```

Comment: I THINK the problem is the key or using ref.current, using these two approaches will cause the flickering effect in my opinion. Also i tried your solution and the flickering is there.

Comment: can we try to delay the application of the new source until the next render, which can help prevent the flickering effect.